# Navier-Stokes equations and machine learning

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, st.statistics, numerical-analysis-of-pde, navier-stokes

I am looking for a reference explaining how to solve the Navier-Stokes equations numerically using machine learning algorithms .
Thank you in advance for your help .

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88698/755, https://mathoverflow.net/q/294017.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the earliest papers is [Application of machine learning algorithms to flow modeling and optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/group/ctr/ResBriefs99/petros.pdf) (1999).

> A model reduction can be accomplished by projecting the Navier-Stokes
>   equations on a properly selected lower dimensional phase subspace. A
>   reasonable choice for a “proper” selection criterion for the base of
>   this manifold is the maximization of the energy content of the
>   projection. This operation is called Proper Orthogonal Decomposition
>   (POD), or Linear Principal Components Analysis (PCA).
>
> The linear POD is an approximation of the flow vector $v$ by a finite
>   expansion of orthonormal functions $\phi_n$ such that: $v = V + 
> > \sum_{i=1}^n a_n(t)\phi_n(x)$, where $V$ is the time averaged flow,
>   $\phi_n$ is the set of the first $n$ eigenvectors of the covariance
>   matrix $C = E[(v_i −V )(v_j −V )]$; when this representation for $v$ is
>   substituted in the Navier Stokes equations, the original PDE model is
>   transformed in an ODE model, composed by n equations. The POD can be
>   expressed as a multi-layer feed-forward neural network.

For more recent work, see

- [Convolutional
  Neural Networks for Steady Flow Approximation](https://autodeskresearch.com/publications/convolutional-neural-networks-steady-flow-approximation) (2016)
- [Artificial
  neural network method for solving the Navier–Stokes equations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00521-014-1762-2)
  (2014)